# Updating GUI of Windows 8 C# Metro App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've created a basic Metro App for Win 8 using Visual Studio 11 Ultimate in C#.

The problem here is that I want to display text that dynamically changes with certain events.
An example would be an app where a number is displayed on the screen and increments by 1 whenever the mouse is clicked.

I've using XAML binding to a data structure I've created which does get the values I need to display, but the problem is that as those values change, the numbers that display on the GUI do not change.

How do I bind my XAML to data that dynamically changes so that the XAML display on the GUI changes as well?

Thanks for the help!

-- edit --

I've implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but now I'm receiving an Exception from this line of code:

PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

Here is the Exception information:

The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Comment: Some sample code would help as a starting point here :-)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to change a control outside of the thread that handles it ( based on the HRESULT error code ).

Comment: How are you handling the "clicking" of the mouse? Event in your code behind? An ICommand on your viewmodel? Depending on where you're handling the click, which is also where I'm assuming you're setting your properties to display, you have to marshal the PropertyChanged event back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your "data structure" you're binding to (properly) implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) and invokes the PropertyChanged event when you want to notify the UI of a change.

This is the interface that allows the xaml layer to know when values change in the bound data, and update accordingly.

---

Edit in response to new information:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

This suggests you're raising the property changed from a separate thread, which will potentially cause issues.  You may need to marshal this back to the main thread using [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync).  For details, see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e7ac335f-f076-4be6-9cba-32026518b2c8).

Comment: Only problem is that CoreDispatcher.Invoke is no longer supported.

Comment: @JoshuaMak Yeah - always forget that it needs to switch to RunAsync - fixed.